# Adding thumbnail image of product in Magento Order View Page in Backend

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to show image thumbnail of products in order view page (`sales_order`/`view`) area of Magento. Adding preview image of the product as a column.

I have my line as the below:

```
load($_item->getProductId()); ?>init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75); ?>"   
alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product['name']); ?>" border="0" width="75" />
```

But this just pulls through a blank box with no image at all in it, not even the Magento default image.

It will likely just be name of field or attribute slightly off? Or maybe even casing? But can't really see what I'm doing wrong.

If I replace:

```
load($_item->getProductId());
```

with:

```
load($_item['product_id'])->getData('image')
```

I can pull in the location of the image which shows on the page. But can't get it to work to actually display the image.

Can pull thumbnail of product in fine on the product grid page, but can't locate page to replicate code from.

Any help to polish off above would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final code was the below. To get this working add it to `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`

```
<td class="a-center">
  <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())->load($_item->getProductId());?>
  <p align="center">
  <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" />
  </p>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you share a full code and where did you place it? I also want to retrieve an image for reference in the order view. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can show ordered item image with below code

```
$order   = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);    
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){    
    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    echo  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Looks like a good answer though!

Comment: Could you please explain this answer @JaimeGómez

Comment: If you want to show item image into order section then you can use this code. where $order   = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

Comment: On template path hinting and then edit the file you needed.

Answer (score 0):

this can be helpful for you i think you just need to place  your attribute value

http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2013/01/get-custom-attribute-value-in-magento.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this link will work for any attribute that's not an image. So for colour, size, material etc will be fine. For image, it will just pull through the location of the image, e.g. Image /2/5/25291.jpg rather than displaying the actual image. Really looking for a way to show a thumbnail of product image, the attribute name is just 'image' and then after this, be able to link it through to frontend where product is, so pull in url key after too.

Comment: i think you need to cancatinate the pending image path in the code just try to check the path of image for two products from the frontend and compare there path if they have the some part same than you can cancatinate it with the code and hopefully you will get the image

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get working, final code was:
 <td class="a-center"><?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())->load($_item->getProductId());?><p align="center"><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" /></p></td>